# SQL Server 2012 check constraint error on udf

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

Just trying to make a simple function in SQL Server 2012 to be used as a check constraint. Cant get past this error.  Thanks for any help!

The error I receive:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The ALTER TABLE statement
>   conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CheckBatchQuantity". The
>   conflict occurred in database "Ians23_SnackManufacturer", table
>   "dbo.Batch", column 'BatchQuantity'.

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udfBatchNumber2
(@BatchQuantity int)

RETURNS int 

AS    

BEGIN
DECLARE @Return int
IF @BatchQuantity >10 
    SET @Return = 0

ELSE
    SET @Return = 1

RETURN @Return 
END
```

---

```
ALTER TABLE Batch
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckBatchQuantity
check ((dbo.[udfBatchNumber](BatchQuantity)) <= 0)
```

Comment: Please format your code in this post so we can read it. You do so by indenting each line with 4 spaces.

Comment: thx, i was just in middle of editing that.

Comment: Without seeing the database and dbo.Batch table definition, I assume the problem is most likely with the dbo.Batch data itself. An existing value in the BatchQuantity column must be less than or equal to 0 assuming the BatchQuantity column is an `int`.

Comment: i am trying to make sure no inputs are greater than 10 (BatchQuantity should be <=10)

Comment: You don't need a special UDF to do that. Having said that, the combination of your UDF and your check is doing the opposite of what you say you want.

Comment: i know, its just a practice in creating a udf and leveraging it as a constraint.

Comment: i want my udf to return 0 or 1 (depending on @quantity) and my check constraint to check which was returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to existing records in `Batch` table whose `BatchQuantity` is **greater** than `zero`.

First update/remove the records whose `BatchQuantity > 0` then create the check constraint

```
update Batch
set BatchQuantity = NULL
Where BatchQuantity > 0

ALTER TABLE Batch
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckBatchQuantity
check ((dbo.[udfBatchNumber](BatchQuantity)) <= 0)
```

or you can create the constraint with `NOCHECK` which will not check the existing data

```
ALTER TABLE Batch WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckBatchQuantity
check ((dbo.[udfBatchNumber](BatchQuantity)) <= 0)
```